# Arduino/Raspberry Pi IOT Project and mobile application

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, arduino, raspberry-pi, iot

So what I have right now is:

- A Raspberry Pi 3B+ and an Arduino Uno connected by serial communication
- A react native expo mobile application
- Firebase real-time database

For the Raspberry Pi and Arduino, the raspberry pi executes a python code that runs the Arduino code that takes values from a sensor connected to the Arduino Uno.

What I'm trying to do is use the react native app to execute the python code and store the values recorded from the sensor in the real-time database.

I've been searching all sorts of documentation and videos, but could not find something that relates to what I'm trying to do.

If anyone could give me a lead on how to approach this subject, it would be much appreciated.

Do let me know if any of you need any more clarification on the subject.

Comment: You would need to use a server to communicate between the react native app and the python code.

Comment: @caslawter can you give me a bit more information on how to proceed?

Comment: You can host a server with the raspberry pi using libraries like Flask. Once it's successfully hosted, you can create an API that will trigger the Arduino to record the sensor's data. Once the API is created, you can just use it in your React native app.

Comment: @caslawter I've been able to host a web server. About the API can you direct me to the software, website, or steps I should follow? .. If possible of course

Comment: There are 2 parts you need to complete, first you would need to connect your server to firebase using the token that was given to you. There should be guides on how to set up firebase for python and react native. Secondly, in your python server, you would be using flask to communicate between react native and your python code. There are countless documentation on how to create an API in flask.

Comment: The structure of the API would be something like this. When react native sends a message to the python server to turn on the Arduino, flask will receive the request and trigger the Arduino to start recording the sensor data. Arduino will send the data back to Flask which will then be uploaded to firebase. It thens send the ok message back to react native telling react native that the sensor data is ready for use. Finally, react native will reterive the data that is stored in firebase.

Comment: @caslawter Thank you for pointing me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, The data pipeline is as follows. I know that there is a firebase library for both python and react native. Using this library, connect to firebase realtime and make the necessary data pipeline.

[image: Architecture]